# A Proud Husband

Tags: field-recording

This isn't really a question, just a little bit of a story.  You can read on if you like, but it's just a little gush from me...

Three years ago my then not even girlfriend returned to Atlanta from traveling around the South.  I was the sound recordist/boom-op for a week long production that was all over the city.  She would come by set, hang out, and watch us work.  After each day, we would stay up late, talk, and fall asleep awkwardly draped across couches or on the floor.  After that week, we started dating.  A year later, we got engaged and were married soon after.

Immediately after we started dating, she started with no film experience PAing on some of the shoots I was on.  She then moved up to boom-oping on a few short films and eventually was the sound recordist on shorts I was producing or ADing.

This morning I packed all the sound gear up in addition to every mic I had, every spare cable, every adapter and little gadget, even my Zoom Q3HD (just in case!) and sent my wife out the door with a kiss.  She is now on her first ever feature film shoot as the sound recordist and boom-op - not one of those ultra-low budget deals either!  It's a unique feature with women writers, DP, director, and even post sound designer.  I'm sure her being a woman helped a little, but really she is probably one of the most skilled recordists in the area.

I am so proud to have a wife that has tuned her ear to become a great sound woman and is making a name for herself on her own.  She is still learning, but has a strong presence (she's over six feet tall) on set and a desire to better her craft.  She's smart, attentive, confident, and a beauty.  To add to that, she's already a fiber designer and accomplished in the knitting world.

I'm a lucky guy and in love.

Thanks for indulging, SSD.

Comment: That's really quite sweet. One of the nicest stories I've heard from crew couples. More often than not, they seem to not work out. Good on ya!

Comment: @Steve Urban - looks like you've got some competition.

Comment: lol @Utopia's comment.

This is awesome! I'm officially jealous for what I believe is the second time in my life (the other is Steve and Karol. So awesome they have a shared passion in the professional realm as well).

Comment: @VCProd - That's awesome that she's a knitter (is that the correct term instead of seamstress?). Maybe she can make you guys custom matching wind-socks and zeppelin covers. lol

Comment: *I should clarify that I mean jealous in a respectful and "happy for you guys" way.

Comment: made me smile. happy for you.

Comment: @Syndicate - Hmm, I never thought of that!  I should see if she will knit colorful covers for the mics :)

Comment: @VCProd  This is really cool.  Speaking as a woman, what I like best about this story is that you have been such an open resource and supporter of her development as a recordist.  It is always a mystery to me why more women don't geek on sound.  I too am part of an audio couple and it really is a real gift to be able to relate to my husband about the frustrations and joys of what we do.  You both seem very blessed to me.  Thank you for sharing.

Comment: I want to know why I haven't seen her on SSD. Keeping this your little secret, eh? :-)

Answer (score 1):

Fantastic!!! To have someone so special in your life that also shares your passions and interests on a professional as well as an emotional level is quite rare. You also must be a special kind of person to attract someone like this. Happy growing!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I wish I had a girlfriend that liked sound recording